# ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `config' for #<Rails::App>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rails-engines

I wrote a full rails engine, and trying to test (with RSpec) my controller.

Error only occurred, when `render` method called. On `return` or `redirect` methods all works fine. And problem only with tests. I use dummy app.

stack:

```
  # Failure/Error: get(:search, params)
  ActionView::Template::Error:
      undefined method `config' for #<Rails::App:0x000000034d9ee8>
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails.rb:78:in `root'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:175:in `inspect'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:334:in `identifier_method_name'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:330:in `method_name'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:267:in `compile'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:244:in `block in compile!'
  # <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:232:in `compile!'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:144:in `block in render'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `block in render_template'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__3295526729938120009__process_action__2756155078140629527__callbacks'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_controller/metal/testing.rb:17:in `process_with_new_base_test'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:490:in `process'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:54:in `process'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:407:in `get'
  # ./spec/controllers/pretty_search_controller_spec.rb:37:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `instance_eval'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `block in run'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_exec'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_eval_with_args'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `instance_eval_with_args'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in run'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:104:in `call'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:104:in `run'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:446:in `run_hook'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:340:in `run_around_each_hooks'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:256:in `with_around_each_hooks'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:111:in `run'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:390:in `block in run_examples'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `map'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `run_examples'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:371:in `run'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `block in run'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `map'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `run'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `block in run'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `map'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `run'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `block in run'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `map'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `run'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in run'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `map'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block in run'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:58:in `report'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
  # /home/shooma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

In which direction i should dig?

[engine on GitHub](https://github.com/shooma/pretty_search/tree/tmp2)

UPD:
when in controller call `render` - I got error.

but if in controller call `render :text => 'foo'` - test passes.

problem somewhere in dummy application config. but i can't locate it.

UPD2:

falling spec:

```
  context 'action should return @options and @results' do
    it '@options should be an instance variable, which eq hash of three keys' do
      get(:search, params)
      # do something
    end
  end
```

controller:

```
def search
  # do something
  render
end
```

RESOLUTION:

It was my fault. Problem was in overloading some internal rails classes in test environment. Sorry for spent time, @sameera207, and thank you for participation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the difference between `render` and `redirect` is, redirect loads your redirected action but render doesn't,

Ex:

```
  def new
    @user = User.new 
  end

  def create
    if <some conditions>
       redirect_to 'new' 
    else
       render 'new'
    end
  end
```

so when you call `render`, it doesnt create `User.new`, only redirect will. So probably you are rendering an action which loads something from `config`.

So the solutions would be

```
def new
        @user = User.new 
      end

      def create
        if <some conditions>
           redirect_to 'new' 
        else
           @user = User.new
           render 'new'
        end
      end
```

I hope u get the idea. and if you could post the `spec` someone might be able to help easier ..

Comment: thanks for answer! but I think that the problem in `Dummy:App`'s config (question updated).

Comment: i edit the question, if it's too cropped, [here](https://github.com/shooma/pretty_search/blob/tmp2/spec/controllers/pretty_search_controller_spec.rb#L36) is a full spec, and [here](https://github.com/shooma/pretty_search/blob/tmp2/app/controllers/pretty_search/pretty_search_controller.rb#L23) is a full original controller

Comment: for me it works, I got a git clone, ran bundle install and `from the plugin directory you should run spec` (not inside the dummy dir). following is the result , https://gist.github.com/sameera207/8038652